# Passing an array from a constructor to a method?

Tags: java

When I try to run it I get this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
I want to initialize the array in the constructor SimpleIntegerStack and use it later on in the methods that follow...

```
package datastructures.simple_integer_stack;

public class SimpleIntegerStack {
int maxSize;
private int stack[]=new int[maxSize];

public SimpleIntegerStack(int maxSize) {

    int stack[]= new int [maxSize];
}

public void push(int element) {
    int i=-1;
    boolean stop = false;

    do{
        if(stack[i]==0){
            stack[i]=element;
            stop=true;
        }
        i++;

    }while(stop=false && i<stack.length);

}

public void pop() {
    int i=0;

    while(stack[i]!=0 && i<stack.length){
        i++;
    }
    if(i!=0)
        stack[i] = 0;
}

public int top() {
    int stacktop=-1;
    int i=0;
    boolean empty = true;
    while(stack[i]!=0 && i<stack.length-1){
        i++;
        empty=false;
    }
    if(i==stack.length-1){
        if (stack[i+1]==0){
            empty=true;
        }
        else stacktop=stack[i+1];
    }
    if(empty=false)
        stacktop=stack[i-1];
    return stacktop;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "int" from the code below:

```
public SimpleIntegerStack(int maxSize) {

    // dont do this:  int stack[]= new int [maxSize];
    stack = new int[maxSize];  
}
```

What you have done is to declare a local variable, `stack` in the constructor. This variable happens to have the same name as the instance variable.  When the constructor function completes, the local variable goes out of scope.

Thus the instance variable, `stack` is not affected by calls to the constructor.